# conditional IF statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to build a flexible project that can toggle on/off which tier of data is outputted, Basic or Deluxe.  I have a Linq query that outputs my basic package of data and headers (Company, URL, Country).  Let's say I also have a deluxe package of data  (columns are Address, Revenue Range, CompanyAge).  My end goal is to implement a toggle such that if the IsDeluxe field in my SQL table is true, then add on the deluxe headers and output the deluxe data in addition to the basic fields.  So far I have something like:

```
var dataPackage = from c in db.company select new { c };

if(IsClientDeluxe == true)
    {
     HeaderRow.Add(String.Format("{0}", "Address"));
     HeaderRow.Add(String.Format("{0}", "Revenue Range"));
     HeaderRow.Add(String.Format("{0}", "Company Age"));
    }

var results = dataPackage.ToList()
```

However, my IF condition won't recognize my sql column and I have no idea how to write the data to the appropriate row.  Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What columns are you trying to access from db.company?

Comment: the first three for the basic tier of data (Company, URL, country), and the next three from the deluxe tier (Address, Rev Range, Company Age) if IsClientDeluxe == true

Answer (score 0):

Can't you assume everything is an element that contains the valid additional headers?

```
var dataPackage = from c in db.company select new { 
                c.IsDeluxe,
                c.Address,
                c.RevenueRange,
                c.CompanyAge };


var actualItems = new List<SomeObject>();

foreach(var item in dataPackage)
{
     var addingItem = new SomeObject();

     if(item.IsDeluxe)
     {
         //Initialize some object one way
     }
     else
     {
         //Initialize some object another way
     }

     actualItems.Add(adding);

}
```

It can be a lot easier to just use Linq-to-Sql to get your data for you and when you have to do more involved decisioning you express that in regular C#